# Xmind exports pdf without text?

Tags: xmind

I installed xmind 8 pro on playonlinux. It worked good but export pdf[map] and svg with a map without any text. Kindly guide me on setting up wineprefix to correct that issue.[image]

I have tried xmind8 linux version from the website. The pdf turns out to be great, but svg export has problem.

Here is one screenshot of svg from "print dialog"

[image]

Here is one screenshot of svg from "export dialog"

[image]

I have full faith in the window version, that is why i want to seek guide in case of wine.

Comment: Xmind has normal native linux versions - in all kinds - Snap, AppImage and FlatPak. Install one of them to remove the problem in question.

Comment: The normal version works great but it does not deal with svg export properly as indicated in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i configured playonlinux by "Install Components", then select gdiplus

The program gives a crisp output(as desired and better than the native version) with text for both "pdf" and "svg"(Export only, absent in print dialog but a minor price).

Comment: My xmind 8 on wine opens pdf(no matter what software on linux) attached to its branches very well, but it could not open other files(atatched) like (office files associated with other pol installation and libre office).